# How to check aws step function activity completed or not using c#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-sdk-net

I have step function.in which two parallel activities are there. now I want to display step function stage in in my asp.net page.

How do I know whether the specific activity completed or not using c# code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use C# sdk api and use below method, it will return status whether it is completed or not.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/StepFunctions/MStepFunctionsDescribeExecutionDescribeExecutionRequest.html

This will give you overrall status.

In case you want to track status of specific activity. Add next step TASK to call your api which would update your local db. Now your Website can read data from your local db to show it is completed or not. Would save you cost to read in and out from aws.